# Run Jupyter Notebook non interactively

Tags: keras, browser, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I have an Ubuntu virtual machine on Azure. I am running a Jupyter notebook on this VM to train a Keras sequential model. The model takes ~24 hours to fully train. Is there a way to run the notebook without using my browser. So leaving the Jupyter server and notebook running in the background BUT for all results/outputs/plots to be displayed within the Jupyter notebook?

When I try to do this by starting the Jupyter notebook interactively through my browser, then closing my browser but leaving the Jupyter kernel running, the cells within the notebook will execute but no output is displayed.

I have looked at this similar question: [Running an IPython/Jupyter notebook non-interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905350/running-an-ipython-jupyter-notebook-non-interactively)
But this is dealing with a different issue where the kernel is not running when trying to execute

This question is for the same issue: [Jupyter notebook output cell freezes (Keras related?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133916/jupyter-notebook-output-cell-freezes-keras-related)
But the solution is to save some outputs in csv files which is not ideal

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this question looking for the same functionality in Jupyter;

Unfortunately as of May 2020 an issue relating to this is still open: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1647

Therefore it looks like it is currently not possible to run Jupyter notebooks with the browser closed.